# Puts ruby hash in random order

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, zip

I wrote a code that matches every letter from an alphabet with another character (string with length 1) and i turned the two into a hash:

```
Hash[String.alphabet.zip String.alphabet]
# String.alphabet returns an array with 0:A, 1:B, ... ,25:Z
# I take two times the alphabet to demonstrate
```

But when i print the hash with

```
puts "#{hash.keys.join}\n#{hash.values.join}"
```

it gives me

```
VKWLAXMBYNCZODPEQFRGSHTIUJ
VKWLAXMBYNCZODPEQFRGSHTIUJ
```

, which - while being correct - is hard to read if i wanna see if letters are matched correctly, i'd much prefer an output in the form of

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

[The print method works correctly on other hashes and is by my knowledge correct]

**So: How can i 'zip' the arrays while keeping the original order of keys?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers about ordered hashes are correct, but in your case you don't necessarily have to *keep* the hash in order, you can just sort it for your output.

```
puts hash.sort.transpose.map(&:join)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorted hashes you can use in Ruby 1.9.x. In Ruby 1.8.7 Hashes are unsorded

From API:

A `Hash` is a collection of key-value pairs. It is similar to an `Array`, except that indexing is done via arbitrary keys of any object type, not an integer index. The order in which you traverse a hash by either key or value may seem arbitrary, and will generally not be in the insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `zip`, it's the `Hash` that's the problem.

A hash table ordinarly (in the general world of computer science) doesn't keep track of the order that data's inserted (or any other sort order) all it wants to know about is lookup. If you want to traverse a hash table to see everything that's in it, you end up traversing the elements in order of the buckets where the elements are stored. That's typically some modulo of the hash function. With a good hash function, that's essentially a random order.

In Ruby 1.8, that's how hash tables are implemented.

Realizing that people expect their Hashes to remember the order of elements, the Ruby developers added some kind of linked list to their hash tables in Ruby 1.9, so that you could traverse the elements in a non-random order.